# EF Core - Table columns are automatically sorting

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have just added a few new models to my .NET Core application that is currently using EF code-first migrations. Previous models have migrated fine and in the order of my model properties, but things seem to have changed now. New models are sorted first by key values, then alphabetically.

Here's an example...

My logging class:

```
[Table("Logs")]
public class LogEntry
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public LogEntryType Type { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    public DateTime LogTimeUtc { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

I type into my package manger console in VS 2017:

`add-migration InitialCreate -Context LoggingContext`

and that produces this in the migration builder:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Logs",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                LogTimeUtc = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                Message = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(4000)", maxLength: 4000, nullable: true),
                StackTrace = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(4000)", maxLength: 4000, nullable: true),
                Type = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Logs", x => x.Id);
            });
```

Notice that the order of the properties have changed? This same ordering is then applied to the database when using:

`update-database -Context LoggingContext`

How can I get EF Core to stop ordering my columns? The last time I made a new table for this application (using the exact same method, 2 months back) it retained its order, and I don't think I've done anything to it since.

Comment: looks like this is still an `open` issue: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10059

Comment: That issue looks more like an enhancement request. I'm expecting my problem to either be misconfigured settings that I can't find or a recent update "feature" that I haven't found a work around for (except for manually updating the migration scripts like I'm needing to currently do).

Comment: It happens in 2.0, after `EF Core 2.1` updates migrations to initially generate columns for tables in the same order as properties are declared in classes.Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#better-column-ordering-in-initial-migration)

Comment: @XingZou good pickup! That was the problem. Judging by the commits, there was a downgrade a few months ago for "compatibility problems". Just changed the version locally and it worked fine. I'll need to have a discussion with my team after the Christmas break about what the cause for the downgrade was. Post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens in 2.0, EF Core 2.1 or after updates migrations to initially generate columns for tables in the same order as properties are declared in classes.Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#better-column-ordering-in-initial-migration).